# How does connections throught ssh tunnel appear to host

Tags: networking, ssh, ssh-tunnel

Not sure how to title the question, but the situation is as follows:

I have 3 servers:

`USER`, `TUNNEL`, `TARGET`

on `TUNNEL` I run command

`TUNNEL:~$ ssh -nNT -L 0.0.0.0:22222:localhost:22 TARGET`

which enables me to ssh from `USER` to `TARGET` by connecting to `TUNNEL` at port 22222

`USER:~$ ssh TUNNEL -p 22222`

The question is:
From the `TARGET` point of view, will the connection appear as coming from `USER` or `TUNNEL`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you connect to the server via a forwarded port, it will be seen as originating locally.

TIP: You can directly connect to target using using *[ProxyJump](http://man.openbsd.org/ssh.1#J)*. 
It can be used as 
`$ ssh -J user@TUNNEL user@TARGET`. In case you have an older version of openssh client, you can make use of *[ProxyCommand](http://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config.5#ProxyCommand)*.

Comment: So is there a way for `TARGET` to actually know the original IP of the client? I am asking because: what if I whitelist IP (at `TARGET`) of the `TUNNEL` and disable everything else - Will I be able to ssh into `TARGET` from `USER` ? (Too afraid to try). Is this how one sets up bastions/jump servers?

Comment: It'll definitely work if you whitelist the tunnel and block all other external IP. That is a common practise in jump box setups.

Answer (score 1):

How hard is to set that up and try? For example using the `$SSH_CONNECTION` environment variable:

```
USER:~$ ssh TUNNEL -p 22222 'echo $SSH_CONNECTION'
```

But the first connection creates port forwarding, which is transparent for the application that is using it. So the second TCP connection starts on USER machine, reaches TUNNEL machine and from there is transparently forwarded to the TARGET machine. So once the TARGET asks from where the connection comes, he will get the real public IP address of USER.

Comment: Thanks, did not know about the `SSH_CONNECTION` variable! However when I ran that, i got `127.0.0.1 43452 127.0.0.1 22`  So I don't get the real USER's public ip from that one. Is there a way how to "dig deeper"?

Comment: So then it is not so transparent as I hoped in the answer. But I believe you will be able to figure out now.